# Generate NTLMv2 hash and validation

Tags: java, hash, clojure, ntlmv2

I'm working on a small Clojure project where I need to be able to generate an NTLMv2 hash from a plain string. The value will be used to populate the sambaNTPassword field in an openLDAP instance. I expected this would involve calling on some Java libs to do the heavy lifting and started with this [java example](https://gist.github.com/abythell/4757703). However, the results are not looking right and I've seen some posts which indicate jcifs may not be a good solution for NTLMv2.

So I have two questions

1. Does anyone know of a simple script I can use to generate NTLMv2 hashes which I could use as a check scripts i.e. compare to the output I'm getting from my solution.
2. Any suggestions on other Java libraries which might be better for this task?

Answer (score 2):

Actually found the answer to both my questions with a little more searching and a bit more debugging of my Clojure.  Figured I'd post it here just in case it is useful to someone else.

Last part first - found a web based NTLMv2 hash generator, so was able to use it to verify my output. See [Browserling NTLM Hash Generator](https://www.browserling.com/tools/ntlm-hash).

Now, my solution. I ended up getting jcifs to work fine. After installing the jcifs.jar into my local maven repo (using lein-localrepo), it was extremely easy - really do think I prefer using Clojure even when most of the code is already in Java. I'm no clojure expert, but this should be reasonably clear (I hope)

```
(ns cifs-clj.core
  (:import [jcifs.util Hexdump MD4])
  (:gen-class))

(defn hash-nt-password [pwd]
  (let [pwd-bytes (.getBytes pwd "UnicodeLittleUnmarked")
        md4 (doto (MD4.)
              (.engineUpdate pwd-bytes 0 (alength pwd-bytes)))
        hash-bytes (.engineDigest md4)]
    (Hexdump/toHexString hash-bytes 0 (* 2 (alength hash-bytes)))))
```